# asp.net web api c# interface dataprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, interface, crud

Please look into code, just i found following error when i call interface into dataprovider

error line::: public class UserDataProvider : IUserDataProvider

error text::: 'UserDataProvider' does not implement interface member 'IUserDataProvider.gettabs()'

I will be thankfull of you

Web API code in c#

Interface code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAPIceoTransaction.Models;

namespace WebAPIceoTransaction.DataProvider
{
public interface IUserDataProvider
{
   Task<IEnumerable<TabMain>> Gettabs();

    Task<TabMain> Gettab(int fid);

    Task Addtab(TabMain Tab);

    Task Updatetab(TabMain Tab);

    Task DeleteTab(int fid);
}
}
```

DataProvider Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WebAPIceoTransaction.Models;
namespace WebAPIceoTransaction.DataProvider

{
public class UserDataProvider : IUserDataProvider
{
    private readonly string connectionString = "Server=******;Database=****;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    private SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public async Task AddTab(TabMain tabmain)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FName", tabmain.FName);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FCompany", tabmain.FCompany);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FDate", tabmain.FDate);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FAmount", tabmain.FAmount);

            dynamicParameters.Add("@FPaid", tabmain.FPaid);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FTransferType", tabmain.FTransferType);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FChequeNo", tabmain.FChequeNo);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FBank", tabmain.FBank);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FAccountNo", tabmain.FAccountNo);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@Purpose", tabmain.Purpose);


            await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(
                "spAddTab",
                dynamicParameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

    public async Task DeleteTab(int fid)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParameters.Add("@Fid", fid);
            await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(
                "spDeleteUser",
                dynamicParameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

    public async Task<TabMain> GetTab(int fid)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParameters.Add("@fid", fid);
            return await sqlConnection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<TabMain>(
                "spGetTab",
                dynamicParameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TabMain>> GetTabs()
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            return await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<TabMain>(
                "spGetTabs",
                null,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

    public async Task UpdateTab(TabMain tabmain)
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
            var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FName", tabmain.FName);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FCompany", tabmain.FCompany);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FDate", tabmain.FDate);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FAmount", tabmain.FAmount);

            dynamicParameters.Add("@FPaid", tabmain.FPaid);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FTransferType", tabmain.FTransferType);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FChequeNo", tabmain.FChequeNo);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FBank", tabmain.FBank);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@FAccountNo", tabmain.FAccountNo);
            dynamicParameters.Add("@Purpose", tabmain.Purpose);
            await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(
                "spUpdateTab",
                dynamicParameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Just as the error states, your class doesn't implement the method `Gettabs()`.  It *does* implement the method `GetTabs()`, but since C# is case-sensitive that's not the same method.  (It's also worth noting that in your "error message" you reference `gettabs()`, which is different from *both*.  Casing is important.)

Comment: Thank you david, error is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface you have it defined as

```
Task<IEnumerable<TabMain>> Gettabs();
```

but you implement it like this

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TabMain>> GetTabs()
```

C# is a case sensitive language, so you need to either change your implementation method name or your interface method name. I would change the interface method name to `GetTabs` to go with the standard naming convention